# How do you password protect a page with Wicket?

Tags: wicket

I want to password protect a webpage in Wicket so the user may only access it if he/she has logged in.

I'd also like the page to show the login page, and then after logging in the original page the user was trying to get to.

How is this done with wicket?  I've already created a login page and extended the session class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The framework-supplied way is to provide an [IAuthorizationStrategy](http://wicket.apache.org/docs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/authorization/IAuthorizationStrategy.html) instance for your application, e.g., by adding to your Application `init()` method:

```
init() {
    ...
    getSecuritySettings().setAuthorizationStrategy(...)
}
```

A working example of Wickets authorization functionality is on Wicket Stuff [here](http://wicketstuff.org/wicket/authorization/), which demonstrates some reasonably complex stuff. For really simple cases, have a look at the [SimplePageAuthorizationStrategy](http://wicket.apache.org/docs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/authorization/strategies/page/SimplePageAuthorizationStrategy.html). At a very basic level, this could be used like so (taken from the linked Javadoc):

```
SimplePageAuthorizationStrategy authorizationStrategy = new SimplePageAuthorizationStrategy(
    MySecureWebPage.class, MySignInPage.class)
 {
        protected boolean isAuthorized()
        {
            // Authorize access based on user authentication in the session
            return (((MySession)Session.get()).isSignedIn());
        }
 };
 getSecuritySettings().setAuthorizationStrategy(authorizationStrategy);
```

**Edit in response to comment**

I think the best way forward, if you're just going to use something like `SimplePageAuthorizationStrategy` rather than that class itself. I did something like this to capture pages that are annotated with a custom annotation:

```
IAuthorizationStrategy authorizationStrategy = new AbstractPageAuthorizationStrategy()
 {
        protected boolean isPageAuthorized(java.lang.Class<Page.class> pageClass)
        {
            if (pageClass.getAnnotation(Protected.class) != null) {
                return (((MySession)Session.get()).isSignedIn());
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
 };
```

Then you'd need to register an [IUnauthorizedComponentInstantiationListener](http://wicket.apache.org/docs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/authorization/IUnauthorizedComponentInstantiationListener.html) similar to what is done in [SimplePageAuthorizationStrategy](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/wicket/trunk/wicket/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/authorization/strategies/page/SimplePageAuthorizationStrategy.java) (link is to the source code), which should be something like:

```
new IUnauthorizedComponentInstantiationListener()
{
    public void onUnauthorizedInstantiation(final Component component)
    {
    if (component instanceof Page)
    {
        throw new RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException(MySignInPage.class);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new UnauthorizedInstantiationException(component.getClass());
    }
    }
});
```

Comment: how do you use SimplePageAuthorizationStrategy with more than one page?  I'd prefer not to use the base class of my webpages as the first parameter.