# Is there any nice authentication solution for Wicket?

Tags: wicket

Is there any nice authentication solution for Apache Wicket? I mean something rather complete with registration form, login form, remember me, lost password, email confirmation/activation etc. ?

I know about this http://wicket.apache.org/learn/projects/authroles.html but its very basic and I'm probably trying to find something built on top of this but more complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want a simple solution try this [How do you password protect a page with Wicket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901285/how-do-you-password-protect-a-page-with-wicket)

And [here](http://tomaszdziurko.pl/2012/09/remember-functionality-apache-wicket/) an example of an implementation of remember me using wicket.

About lost password, email confirmation/activation etc i think you'll have to do it yourself.